# The error occurs in the line "ellipse = v2.fitEllipse(cnt)"

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, math

I tried to write a program that searches for those parts that have
circular elements (holes, shape, etc.). The program should describe
an ellipse of a certain color around the found contours and output the coordinates
of its center. Unfortunately, the program outputs an error in the following line:

```
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
```

The error itself is as follows:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\shapedescr.cpp:360: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) There should be at least 5 points to fit the ellipse in function 'cv::fitEllipseNoDirect'
```

Help me fix this error! The code itself is presented below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# set color range for object search (in this case - blue)
hsv_min = np.array((100, 50, 50), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((130, 255, 255), np.uint8)

# open image
image=r"C:\1\detail.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(image)
print(img)

# convert image to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# create mask for finding objects with specified color
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)

# find contours of objects on the image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# iterate through contours and find ellipses
if contours:
    for cnt in contours:
        area_a = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
        area = int(math.pi * ellipse[1][0] * ellipse[1][1] / 4)
        if area > 1200 and math.fabs(area - area_a) < 470:
            center = (int(ellipse[0][0]), int(ellipse[0][1]))
            cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, (200, 100, 25), 4)
            cv2.putText(img, f"Center: {center}", (center[0] + 20, center[1] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
else:
    print("Contours not found")
# display results on the image
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What does the contour `cnt` look like? Most likely it has less than 5 points...

Comment: I fixed this problem, the image starts, but the contours are not searched on it